# How to add an item to a list after every xth item in Java

Tags: java, list, loops, arraylist, listiterator

Wondering what's the most elegant way to achieve the following:

"Add an item after every xth item in a list".

I have this which is working but looks very ugly to me:

```
ListIterator<Something> it = items.listIterator();
    int i = 0;
    int breakPoint = 3;
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        it.next();
        i++;
        if(i == breakPoint ) {
            it.add(new Something()....);
            i = 0;
        }
    }
```

I'd prefer doing this without using external libraries and such. Any more elegant ways which also are readable and not relying on tricks?

Comment: You can simplify the logic by using `%` ... `if(i % 3 == 0) ... add() ... i++`. Then you would not need the breakPoint-variable.

Comment: I would be more worried about the efficiency than the elegance, per se. I know that you should focus on writing readable code, but it is all to easy to write strangely slow code when doing something like this. Unless you're dealing with a linked list, adding in the middle of the list is going to be a killer. My approach would be to allocate empty space for the extra items at the end of the list, then shuffle the elements along.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an iterator, use `void add(int index, E element)`:

```
for (int i = 3; i < items.size(); i+=3) {
    items.add (i++, new Something());
}
```

This will start by adding an element at index 3. Note that the original element at index 3 will move to index 4, which is why I have `i++` inside the loop (since the next element should be added at index 7, not 6).

Comment: I got `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` with your example.

Comment: @EugeneKirin Which `List` implementation did you use? If you used some immutable list (or constant size list), `add` would fail. It works fine with `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: I used `Arrays.asList("item1", "...");`

Comment: @EugeneKirin That explains it. `Arrays.asList` returns a `List` of fixed size (since it's backed by the array used to create it), so it doesn't support `add`.